# PHP generate all possible String

Tags: php

I want to set for example "a**". 
And now I want to create an array with all possible strings containing an "a" and two other chars. So aaa, aab, aac, aad, ..., aba, abb, abc, abd, ... axx

Is this possible with PHP? Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Perfectly possibly, I'd suggest starting by looking at `foreach` loops, with `range('a','z')`

Comment: Funny how I type an answer, and someone else concurrently types it as a comment.

Comment: Please consider consulting the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) before asking additional questions like this one. In particular, take note of the article titled [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which says: "_Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers..._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (range('a','z') as $a)
    foreach (range('a','z') as $b)
        echo "a$a$b\n";
```